# Prevent HTML5 Drag Ghost Image Flying Back

Tags: html, safari, drag-and-drop

I am building a sortable list that uses the HTML5 drag and drop. It works well, but I have a frustrating problem when it comes to the ghost image. The ghost image always wants to fly back to the location that it came from. The result is that if a list item change positions, the ghost image will fly back to the wrong list item.

Ideally, the ghost image should just not show at all after the `onDragEnd` event. I've tried setting the image to an empty image on dragEnd with

```
handleDragEnd(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(0, 0), 0, 0);
    ...
```

but I think that you can only use `setDragImage` in `onDragStart`.

Is there a way to hide the ghost image `onDragEnd`, or at the very least get it to fly back to the correct location?

Comment: How are you swapping the item? I am implementing a similar functionality, before implementing the actual swap the ghost image behaved like this, but after implementing the swap the image doesn't fly back anymore. I think the browser can detect if the initial item has been moved and then it works as you expect.

Comment: please add some sample code to adequately illustrate the issue

Answer (score 7):

The revert effect is the default behavior on Safari, but you can control this default behavior in the HTML that you control. You only need to add a **dragover** event on the zone on which you want to prevent this revert effect and call **e.preventDefault()**. Only limitation: you won't be able to control when user drags the element out of the browser or the frame that you control.

But something like this gets rid of the problem you're describing:

```js
var draggedId;
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAO0lEQVR42u3OMQ0AMAgAsGFiCvCvDQeggoSjVdD4lf0OC0FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBwR0DX1VWkeseHpAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

document.getElementById('a').ondragstart = dragstart_handler;
document.getElementById('b').ondragstart = dragstart_handler;

document.ondragover = (e) => {
  if (draggedId === "a") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function dragstart_handler(e) {
  draggedId = e.target.id;
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0)
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=a draggable=true>
  This element won't revert on dragend.
</div>

<div id=b draggable=true>
  This one will revert.
</div>
```

Comment: running your code example both are flying back (Chrome)